# Configuring router to assign static IPv6 addresses on the LAN, using an ISP-provided static /48 IPv6 network?

Tags: networking, router, ipv6

My ISP provides me with a ["static /48-IPv6 network"](https://www.init7.net/en/support/faq/Statischer-IPv6-Range/). I'd like to assign some "static" (as in out-living router/machine restarts) IPv6 addresses to machines behind that router so they can be exposed to the internet by pointing my domain at their IPv6 addresses. My RT-AC68U router has the following IPv6 options:

- Native
- Stative IPv6
- Passthrough
- <a bunch of IPv4 tunneling options>

Which one is right? There's also a DHCP-PD enable/disable option.

Here's what my ISP claims my (WAN-side) IP is:

```
Your IP address: 2a02:xxxx:4ba4:0:ec11:18e3:aedb:3c66
```

Here's my router's IPv6 LAN settings, after configuring it as "native":

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| LAN IPv6 Address | 2a02:xxxx:4ba4::1 |
| LAN Prefix Length | 48 |
| LAN IPv6 Prefix | 2a02:xxxx:4ba4:: |

Comment: Are those parameters (LAN prefix & length) set manually or automatically? They seem to conflict with the WAN side... What is the prefix length shown for the *WAN* address? Note that having a /48 routed to you does not mean that the subnet size also has to be /48, quite the opposite.

Comment: Those are automatic LAN settings. I'm not sure how to find WAN prefix length on my router.

Comment: Any chance you could get a capture of ICMPv6 Router Advertisements coming from your ISP? (Either the output of `rdisc6 <interface>` or `tcpdump -v -n -i <interface> 'icmp6 and ip6[40] = 134'`, either on your router or from directly connecting some computer to the ISP's WAN link.)

Answer (score 0):

Giving your computers static IPv6 addresses is not a good idea,
as this will expose the computers directly to the internet,
as always accessible at the same address.
The last part of an IPv6 address was defined as random for security reasons.

I would rather suggest using
[Dynamic DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS)
which will let you address your computers via a fixed name, whose IP address
will be updated on reboot.

An example Dynamic DNS supplier is the free
[Dynu](https://www.dynu.com/).
You may download and install a free dynamic DNS client that will run when the
computer is booted and will update instantly the IP address for your DNS name.
After registering, you may add multiple names for multiple computers.

Reference material:
[RFC 7721 - Security and Privacy Considerations for IPv6 Address Generation Mechanisms](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7721)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118681/discussion-on-answer-by-harrymc-configuring-router-to-assign-static-ipv6-address).

Comment: Pity I can't down vote this. A computer can also be a server and servers need static addresses to operate. Why don't you update your answer to mention this? As I'm 100% sure that's what the OP wanted to begin with.

Comment: About your proposed solution, Dynamic DNS for IPv6 is something that simply shouldn't exist. It was a hack to workaround another hack for IPv4.